# UriMapper Problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have the following xaml (nonessential markup removed in the interest of brevity):

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" >
    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
        <uriMapper:UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" 
                                  MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/FMChart/{metricID}/{orgID}" 
                                  MappedUri="/Views/FMChart.xaml?metricID={metricID}&orgID={orgID}"/>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

I'm creating the HyperLinkButton objects dynamically (in code), like so:

```
int metricID = 1;
int orgID = 1;

HyperlinkButton button = new HyperlinkButton();
button.Name        = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
button.TargetName  = "ContentFrame";

// this string doesn't work
string url = string.Format("/FMChart/{0}/{1}", metricID, orgID);

button.NavigateUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
```

When I click the bbutton, the browser renders a blank page, and eventually presents me with a REALLY long stack trace (InvalidOperation exception).  If I take the parameters out of th indicated line:

```
string url = "/FMChart";
```

...it works as expected (brings up the desired page).

I've also  tried the following strings:

> /FMChart/{0}&{1}
>   /FMChart/{0}& amp;{1}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 1):

This `UriMapping` is incorrect:-

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/FMChart/{metricID}/{orgID}" 
    MappedUri="/Views/FMChart.xaml?metricID={metricID}&orgID={orgID}"/>
```

should be:-

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/FMChart/{metricID}/{orgID}" 
    MappedUri="/Views/FMChart.xaml?metricID={metricID}&amp;orgID={orgID}"/>
```

Xaml is xml hence the `&` character when needs to be encoded as the `&amp;` entity.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer, from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3440420/UriMapper-and-stuff-SOLVED-sorta.aspx) was that he had that mapping at the BOTTOM, and that the order of mappings matter.

Just for anyone that's looking.